# What is the sign of the generalized Stieltjes constants $\gamma_{k}(a)$?

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, riemann-zeta, stieltjes-constants

Recall that the [Stieltjes constants $\gamma_{k}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants) appear as the coefficients in the regular part of the Laurent expansion of the Riemann zeta function about $s = 1$:
$$
\begin{align} \zeta(s) 
= \frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \gamma_{k}\:(s-1)^{k}, \quad  \,s\neq 1, \tag1
\end{align}
$$ with $\displaystyle \gamma_{0}=\gamma$, the Euler constant.

Similarly the **generalized Stieltjes constants** $\gamma_{k}(a)$ appear as the coefficients in the regular part
of the Laurent expansion of the Hurwitz zeta function about $s = 1$:
$$
\begin{align} \zeta(s,a) 
= \frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} \gamma_{k}(a)\:(s-1)^{k}, \quad a>0, \,s\neq 1, \tag2
\end{align}
$$ with $\displaystyle \gamma_{0}(a)=-\psi(a)$, the digamma function.

I am aware of a theorem of W. E. Briggs (1955) saying that *infinitely many Stieltjes constants $\gamma_{k}$ take positive values, and 
infinitely many take negative values* and  I am aware of Mitrovic's theorem in the same vein. I've read Mark Coffey's papers.

I'm looking for any interesting material/references about **the sign** of $\gamma_{k}(a),\,a>0$.

Your help is welcome.